"Http failure response for http://servername/article: 0 Unknown Error" Angular
My code runs fine on localhost but when i upload it on a remote server it gives me two errors:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http:servername:4000/getArticleContent' from origin 'http://servername' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

and


message: "Http failure response for http://64.227.111.22:4000/getArticleContent: 0 Unknown Error"

name: "HttpErrorResponse"



I have added cors on the server file and i tried using proxy then i tried adding the port number to it

Please provide revelant code and configuration too, this is not enough information.

This is a very well known cors issue, basically, when you are making a request to a deployed url, which is different from the UI url, the api by default assumes this is a security issue. Just google enable cors in express eg this link

Hi, so I have tried putting the headers as you told me to and it still doesn't work on the remote server..you could click the link from the message to see the error. http://64.227.111.22
